# In android, how can i get app work path use NDK without JNIEnv and JavaVM?

Tags: jnienv

I want to get app work path , use JNIEnv is easy, but will multiple definition with others, and I don't want pass the JNIEnv as a param, Is there any way to get work path without JNIEnv?